# Spring / Resource handler location

Tags: spring-mvc

I have common problem in spring with resource locator and can not figure out where is problem (CSS style is not working:

My .JSP page and HTML code :

```
<head>
<link href="/css/basicStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

My resource locator configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("loginsystem.controllers")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        resolver.setViewClass(
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/LoginSystem/WebContent/WEB-INF/css/");
}
```

}

[image: My project structure in eclipse :]

**SOLUTION :**

After looking in other questions I have found solution  :

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/basicStyle.css/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Can any one explain why pageContext is needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the resources locations from "/LoginSystem/WebContent/WEB-INF/css/" to "/WEB-INF/css/"

Answer (score 0):

There's a dedicated JSP tag for this:

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<link href="<spring:url value="/css/basicStyle.css"/>"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

If you want to have better [resource handling support](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources) in your application, you may also want to register a [ResourceUrlEncodingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.html) in your application.